# How to type this function

Tags: typescript, generics

to everyone!

I just try to type function:

```
export function filterByArrayConditions<T, K> (data: Array<T>, conditions: Array<K>): Array<T> {
    return data.filter(item => {
      for (let key in conditions) {
        if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] !== conditions[key]) return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
};
```

But but it throws an error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'unknown'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)

Comment: Is conditions an array of keys or a object? It's not clear from the code. The type is an array, but then you use `conditions[key]`

Answer (score 0):

You want to let typescript know that `K` is a subype of the keys of `T`. You can do this using `keyof T` as a constraint

```
export function filterByArrayConditions<T, K extends keyof T> (data: Array<T>, conditions: Array<K>): Array<T> {
    return data.filter(item => {
      for (let key of conditions) {
        if (item[key] === undefined) return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWMwGxmCgCEBPAQSigEMyBhHAE0yxwGcAeAFQBo4A0nFBEUTdnADWwMhARxuAPjgAKJjRg0AXHCq0yPRfzTNW2FOx166nAYoCUV6jaVwA3gFgAUHF9wowDBIULjqmgB0CAREUCqswAC2cAC8yp4+fr4I0Kr4gVIycHJwJmJmHPbu3pmZmPJxRAkA2tJkALopyclwqEzAUSjATJUBQSGINPjswADc1TUAvvOZo8G4MFBIs8twC-ZzXgszQA)

You might in fact not net the extra type parameter at all since you are not really creating any relationships between `K` and anything else:

```
export function filterByArrayConditions<T> (data: Array<T>, conditions: Array<keyof T>): Array<T> {
    return data.filter(item => {
      for (let key of conditions) {
        if (item[key] === undefined) return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWMwGxmCgCEBPAQSigEMyBhHAE0yxwGcAeAFQD44AFExowaALjhVaZHrwA0cNM1bYU7CVLqcA1sDIQEcPgEoN1LXzgBvALAAoOI7hRgMJFFzDRAOgQEiUAKswAC2cAC8-LYOTo4I0IL4rnC6ZHAGispsasbW9rGxmIZBRCEA2qkAuhHh4XCoTMB+KMBMuS5uHog0+OzAANz5BQC+Q7Ed7rgwUEgDY3DDxoN2w-1AA)